# Proguard retrace stack variants

Tags: proguard

Can I use the retrace for stack is different from:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Random exception
        at pro.bY.a(ProGuard:576)
        at pro.bO.a(ProGuard:431)
        at pro.bj.a(ProGuard:145)
        at pro.bY.a(ProGuard:522)
        at pro.bj.a(ProGuard:129)
```

E.g, I have this stack:

```
   NullPointerException
   MessageController
   getMessage
   0*7h3f33
   MessageModel
   getCurrentPlace
   0*1F3f14
```

after obfuscate it is:

```
 NullPointerException
   b
   ab
   0*7h3f33
   a
   ac_
   0*1F3f14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your own regular expression with the ReTrace option `-regex`. Cfr. [ProGuard manual > ReTrace Usage](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/usage.html).

The expression is applied per line of stack trace, so you probably have to concatenate some lines from your input trace to get each class/method name pair on a single line.